# tabela teste Jquery

Tags: jquery

Ao clicar na linha 1 em qualquer um button ele mim retorne o valor logo abaixo no article, caso eu clique na mesma linha em um button diferente ele o substitui o valor, caso eu clique na linha 2 ele mim retorna o valor e coloca logo abaixo do outro valor?

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>

<head>
  <title>Untitled</title>
</head>

<body>
    <table>
<tr><th>Linha 1</th>
  <td> <button>valor 01</button> </td>
  <td><button>valor 02</button> </td>
  <td><button>valor 03</button> </td>
  <td><button>valor 04</button> </td>
</tr>
<tr><th>Linha 2</th>
  <td> <button>valor 05</button> </td>
  <td><button>valor 06</button> </td>
  <td><button>valor 07</button> </td>
  <td><button>valor 08</button> </td>
</tr>
<tr><th>Linha 3</th>
  <td> <button>valor 09</button> </td>
  <td><button>valor 10</button> </td>
  <td><button>valor 11</button> </td>
  <td><button>valor 12</button> </td>
</tr>
<tr><th>Linha 5</th>
  <td> <button>valor 13</button> </td>
  <td><button>valor 14</button> </td>
  <td><button>valor 15</button> </td>
  <td><button>valor 16</button> </td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
<section id="Valor"> <legend>Valores Obtidos</legend>
   <article>
        <!--- Aqui fica os valores obtidos dos button--->
   </article>
</section>
</html>
```

Comment: E qual é sua duvida?

Comment: Posta sua dúvida, sei que vc postou la no grupo, mas se for somente pra colocar o código em algum lugar procure algo específico pra isso.
é legal vc compartilhar a dúvida aqui pra que a resposta chege a mais pessoas, abraço.

Comment: Ao clicar na linha 1 em qualquer um button ele mim retorne o valor logo abaixo no article, caso eu clique na mesma linha em um button diferente ele o substitui o valor, caso eu clique na linha 2 ele mim retorna o valor e coloca logo abaixo do outro valor? @Fleuquer Lima

Comment: edita o post e coloca a pergunta antes do código.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pra pegar o texto do botão clicado e o valor da "Linha" que vc colocou ali você poderia fazer algo como:

```
    $("button").click(function(e){
          e.preventDefault();

          // pega o texto do elemento clicado
          var buttonText = $(this).text(); 

          // pega o texto do elemento <th> mais próximo
          var thText = $(this).closest('th').text(); 

          // atribui valor ao article
          $("#valor article").append("<p>Botao: " + buttonText + " Linha: "+ thText +"</p>");
    });
```

Você usou o stack pra publicar seu código, mas edita e coloca sua dúvida, assim mais pessoas encontram a resposta, abraço.